# Ошибка при загрузке/установке Unix дистрибутивов

Tags: linux, unix, amd

Раньше стояла ОС Linux Mint, надоело что постоянно выскакивает при загрузке одна и та же ошибка и приходиться перезагружаться по 5-6 раз, дабы она исчезла (Гугл ответов не давал, говорил только что проблема в драйверах видеокарты), поэтому решил переустановить, списав на битость дистрибутива.

В итоге 10-ый час с бубном, но ОСь я так и не накатил. Пробовал несколько дистрибутивов (Ubuntu, Mint, Tails, чистый Debian), все выдают одну и туже ошибку еще до начала установки (Как и на старой ОС/первоначальной), за исключением последнего, у того экран полосками покрывается, не давая посмотреть что на нём. Так же пока гуглил - нашарил один из ответов, включить IOMMU в биосе, все бы хорошо, но его там нет, думал обновить BIOS, но последняя версия стоит...

После всего этого решил ради интереса накатить винду, поставилась без проблем.

Ноутбук **Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ARR**

Загрузка со встроенной видеокартой

```
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : No southbridge IOAPIC found
AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
```

Загрузка с дискретной видеокартой

```
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[4] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : IOAPIC[5] not in IVRS table
AMD-Vi: [Firmware Bug]: : No southbridge IOAPIC found
AMD-Vi: Disabling interrupt remapping
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.MACO], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20190816/dswload2-323)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-220)
pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1052023/ioapic0-not-in-ivrs-table

Comment: Если всё же найдёте IOMMU, то его нужно выключить, а не включить.